# Query to get especific data from custom search

Tags: mysql

Im coding a custom search box to find starcraft games, but i have no idea how to do the query. FOR EXAMPLE an user search "Player: daniel, who played: zerg vs a terran player on 'x' map"

So i have this tables:

Table games

```
+------------+----------+-------------+----------+
|  game_id   |   map    |    match    |  winner  |
+------------+----------+-------------+----------+
|     7      |     y    |     1v1     |    1     |
|     8      |     x    |    1v1v1    |    2     |
|     9      |     w    |    1v1v1    |    3     |
|     10     |     x    |     1v1     |    1     |
+------------+----------+-------------+----------+
```

Table players

```
+------------+----------+-------------+----------+
|  game_id   |  player  |Civilization |  team    |
+------------+----------+-------------+----------+
|     7      |  Arturo  |   protos    |    1     |
|     7      |  Daniel  |   zerg      |    2     |
|     8      |  Ale     |   Terran    |    1     |
|     8      |  Maria   |   Protos    |    2     |
|     8      |  Daniel  |   zerg      |    3     |
|     9      |  Pablo   |   zerg      |    1     |
|     9      |  Ale     |   protos    |    2     |
|     9      |  Maria   |   protos    |    3     |
|     10     |  Daniel  |   zerg      |    1     |
|     10     |  Oscar   |   terran    |    2     |
+------------+----------+-------------+----------+
```

With the correct query i must get :

Game_id: 8, 1v1v1, daniel (zerg) vs maria (protos) vs ale (terran), map: x 
Game_id:10, 1v1, daniel (zerg) vs oscar (terran), map: x

The problem here is how i get the game WHERE exist a daniel player AND zerg civ AND WHERE an oponent have a terran civ in the same game_id??! And also the game is played in x map?

PD: As you notice each game can have different size of players. Please help. Very much appreciated

Comment: This smells like homework.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: nothing yet, i have no idea how to do it :(

Comment: At the very least, you should have also included what the expected output is.

Answer (score 0):

try this `select g.game_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(p.player,'(', p.Civilization, ')-',g.map) SEPARATOR ' vs ')  from games as g join players p on p.game_id = g.game_id where g.map = 'x' group by g.game_id;`

Comment: Thanks for reply but it only gets a list of rows with map = x :(

Comment: what exactly you want that user will search? accordingly then there  can be modifications in the query

Comment: user can search by player, by map, by civ of the player and civ of the enemy. Like the example above

Comment: you can take a search keyword variable and then can pass in the query so in turn whatever user searches thus you can map with the columns you want to and can get the result, I have shown eg if user searches the player name, likewise you can do with other values as well         
" select g.game_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(p.player,'(', p.Civilization, ')-',g.map) SEPARATOR ' vs ')  from games as g join players p on p.game_id = g.game_id where (p.player like '%deniel%' OR g.map like '%deniel%' OR p.Civilization like '%deniel%') group by g.game_id;"

Comment: Yeah its like you said. I have the php code to get the parameters from the search box but my problem is that i dont know how to do the query to get the precise game where exist a "x" player with "y" civ and his oponent have "z" civ. As you can see in the player table, each player have a row so how to get that?. Its easy for me if i just get a especific player with a civ in the same row, BUT if also i need to search a game where the oponent have a specific civ (in another row but with the same game_id). I dont know how to do that :(